# Are graduate students in mathematics expected to learn information more quickly than undergraduates?

Tags: soft-question

Sheldon Axler writes in LADR that (something along the lines) "if you're reading faster than a page a minute, you're probably going too fast."

I'm now an undergraduate, and I can attest that, yes, to fully understand a page in my texts, it takes about that much time (40 minutes to an hour). It would be reassuring to know if with more maturity, this rate drops or that the expectation to pick up material increases in grad school. Is this so?

Comment: Well, time passing this should become more easy. If you read a text in mathematics of second grade it will be very very very easy.

Comment: Yes, the rate tends to drop (but not all the time because you are studying something new). But you get faster the ideas under some formulation with practice. This is similar to learn some natural language, after you can read faster a book on this language.

Comment: Good news: you will get faster. Bad news: the books will become harder. For some books that you might encounter as a graduate student, an hour per page would be very fast!

Comment: The exact quote from Linear Algebra Done Right is: "You cannot read mathematics the way you read a novel. If you zip through a page is less than an hour, you are probably going too fast."